# Reinitialize uploadify after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, uploadify

The uploadify is working fine initially. But when i repopulate the table using ajax call the uploadify doesn't initialize. And similarly the .sortable of jquery-ui isn't getting initialized either after the same call.

```
var allimages = [];

$('.bulkupload').each(function() {
        var $bulkupload = $(this);
        $bulkupload.uploadify({
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'bulkupload.php',
            'auto'      : true,
            'multi'     : true,
            'buttonText':   'Upload Images',
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                if (data == "1") {
                    var filename = file.name;
                    if ($.inArray(filename, allimages) > -1) {
                        var fi = $.inArray(filename, allimages);
                        allimages.splice(fi, 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        allimages.push(filename);
                    }
                    var productid = $bulkupload.attr("prodid");
                    var sortablename = "#sortable-"+productid;
                    $(sortablename).append("<li filename=\""+filename+"\" style=\"list-style: none;\" class=\"ui-state-default\"><div class=galleryimages><img src=\"products/"+productid+"/"+filename+"\" width=100 border=0><span class=deleteimageicon filename=\""+filename+"\"><img src=\"images/delete.png\" border=0></span></div></li>");
                }
            }
        });
});
$(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var pid = $(this).attr("pid");
        var images = $(this).sortable('toArray', {attribute: 'filename'});
        var dataString = "images="+images+"&pid="+pid+"&action=bulkimageorder";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "filename.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
            }
        });
    }
});
$(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

Comment: Can you check your firebug console and see if you are getting any bugs there.

Comment: the issue is that it won't be initialized because the element on which it is applying is getting reloaded via ajax. So this needs to be re-initialized which is usually done use jquery .on. But unfortunately I don't know how to use same here

Comment: Are you using the jquery 'on' method with the selector so it will delegate the event. I had same issue with 'on' for my ajax content, but after inserting the selector it worked fine after the ajax data is loaded.

Comment: No I am not. I don't know how to use it here in this situation. As you can see I am using .each because I have multiple instances of uploadify. I don't know how to use .on in this situation

Comment: After your ajax call you need to call your uploadify each script again on the new content, use a callback function on your ajax call and do it. Now uploadify will get initialized to newly loaded ajax content.

Comment: I don't want to call it again and again. I know how to do that. I want to define the uploadify only once and use something like .on so that it get reinitialized every time.

Comment: ok i am writing an answer that gives you a idea, check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40104/discussion-between-script-shiva-and-saad-bashir)

Answer (score 1):

The only way i see to do it is implementing a custom event, and catching that with 'on'.

Let the event be, 'my.uploadify.event'

After page load trigger the event to initialize it,

```
$('.bulkupload').trigger('my.uploadify.event');
```

This will cause the event to trigger on the page load. The next step is to fire the event after the ajax data is loaded. Use the above statement in your ajax callback again. Now what this does is, it will fire an event so that the previously set on catches it.

Now wrap your 'each' snippet within this 'on' block,

```
$('.bulkupload').on('my.uploadify.event', function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        // Process
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you want exactly, this is my idea. Now the uploadify gets re-initialized after every event trigger.

Comment: Doesn't work. Like you said I added .trigger in the code which is being loaded through .ajax. And then modified the .each function by adding .on before it like you suggested. But still the uploadify didn't initialize.

Comment: Sorry buddy, just try this one thing. Replace the $('.bulkupload') in the 'trigger' and 'on' function and try $(document). But for the each use your same $('.bulkupload').each()

Comment: Nope didn't work. Used the following
<script type="text/javascript">   $('document').trigger('my.uploadify.event');   </script>
 $('document').on('my.uploadify.event', function(){
 $('.bulkupload').each(function() {

Comment: Okay if you know how to debug javascript. Open up your firebug script console and set up a breakpoint at the 'on' event. See if it is getting triggered or not. Can you try with $(document). Just in case...

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used firebug. I tried to use right now after you asked me and right clicked the link which has .on even and checked all the breakpoints for 'on' but nothing happened.

Comment: There's only one way to solve this, can you create a fiddle of your base code and share me the link. I will see what the problem is.

Comment: It will be hard to create a jsfiddle for this because I am not sure how to do the ajax part in fiddle.